# C# TextFieldParser vs \n

Tags: c#, csv, escaping

I'm trying to read a CSV file that has some `\n` in the text fields.  When I use what I've read in a `DrawString` the `\n` appears in the text, instead of a line break.  Looking at the string in the debugger, it appears that `TextFieldParser` has automagically escaped the string for me.  I don't see any properties in the class documentation that address that behavior.

I've tried working around it with a `String.Replace()`.  But I can't seem to get the escaped \ in *that* correct.

```
string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
String From = @"\\n"; // I put these here so that I could look at them in the debugger
String To = @"\n";
String Output = fields[1].Replace(From, To);
```

It looks like those are also getting escaped all to hell, even though I'm using the @ syntax.

I know this is going to be dirt simple when someone shows it to me.  Please be kind :-)

Edit ----------

```
String Output = fields[1].Replace(@"\n", "\r\n");
```

Tested and works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the debugger, it is *visualizing* the line break for you.  It is not *escaping* it (that is, it is still the ASCII character with hex value 0x10, not two characters '\' and 'n').

DrawString is does not interpret "\n" (Unix-style lines) to mean "begin a new line".

However, if you replace "\n" with "\r\n", it should work fine.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/17e645bf-6751-44d5-a5be-af322b589122/

Comment: DrawString does correctly produce a line break when I use \n in a literal.  The example I cribbed from used a literal.  And I just ran a test with the literal string "Test\nTest".  Hmm.  Found a different way to look at it in the debugger.  I'm only seeing one \ when I click on the magnifying glass icon.  I assume there's a way to look at the hex, but haven't found it, yet.  Been a few years since I last used Visual Studio.

Comment: Edit - Found how to look at the hex

Comment: Okay.  Using the replacement string To = Strings.Chr(13).ToString() + Strings.Chr(10).ToString(); worked